# What is Perfect Forwarding equal to

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I know that this can be used to perform perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename A>
void foo(A&&) { /* */ }
```

This can be used to perform perfect forwarding on a certain type:

```
template <typename A, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<A>, int>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(A&&) { /* */ }
```

But these are just templates for functions, which means, that these get expanded to some functions, which are then used for every special case in which it might be used. However do these get expanded to:

`void foo(A&)` and `void foo(A&&)`

**OR**

`void foo(A&)` and `void foo(A)`

I always thought, it would be the first one, but then I noticed, that in that case, you wouldn't be able to use `A const` as an argument to the function, which certainly works.

However the second would be ambiguous, if you used a normal non-const lvalue. Does it call `foo(A&)` or `foo(A)`?

Comment: `A&&` if supplied with an rvalue, `A &` otherwise, as far as I remember.

Comment: The phrase "perfect forwarding" stems from precisely the fact that `A` can deduce to either of a couple different types, depending on what's passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the first one. The second wouldn't make very much sense: there is no `A` such that `A&&` is a non-reference type.

If the argument is an lvalue of type *cv* `T`, then `A` is deduced as *cv* `T&`. If the argument is an rvalue of type *cv* `T`, then `A` is deduced as *cv* `T` and `A&&` is *cv* `T&&`. So when you pass in a `const` lvalue, the specialization generated is one that can accept a `const` argument.

Comment: Which means it would expand to `A&&` for rvalues, `A&` for lvalues, and `A const&` for const lvalues (but not rvalues)?

Comment: @hgiesel Read it over again: the appropriate cv qualifiers would be deduced for rvalues too. Otherwise the reference binding would not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

They were called originally "**Univeral** **References**" by Scott Meyers, and now "**Forwarding References**".

As you can see, the **references** part has not changed. You pass in any kind of `rvalue`, you get a `rvalue` reference. You pass in any kind of `lvalue`, and you get a lvalue reference. Life is that simple.